# List as map value in grails

Tags: list, grails, groovy, dictionary

I need to populate a Map so that:

- The Key is a String
- The Value is a List of Strings

The process is to go through all the records in a table that has two text fields : "parameter" and "value". "Parameter" is not unique an has many duplicates. So what I intent to do is:

```
def all = MyTable.findAll()
def mymap = [:]

all.each {
  // add to mymap the element "it.value" to the list that has "it.parameter" as key 
}
```

Any clues ?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a IMHO little bit simpler way doing this by using 'withDefault' introduced in Groovy 1.7:

```
all = [
    [parameter: 'foo', value: 'aaa'],
    [parameter: 'foo', value: 'bbb'],
    [parameter: 'bar', value: 'ccc'],
    [parameter: 'baz', value: 'ddd']
]

def myMap = [:].withDefault { [] }
all.each {
    myMap[it.parameter] << it.value
}

assert myMap.size() == 3
assert myMap.foo == ['aaa','bbb']
assert myMap.bar == ['ccc']
assert myMap.baz == ['ddd']
```

Comment: As an aside, with Groovy 1.8+ you can do the following `all.groupBy { it.parameter }.collectEntries { k, v -> [ (k):v*.value ] }` which is potentially simpler again :-)

Comment: Also, prior to Groovy 1.8 you can do: `all.groupBy { it.parameter }.inject( [:] ) { map, val -> map << [ (val.key):val.value*.value ] }`

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `Map.groupBy` method, which will split the collection into a map of groups based on the passed in closure.  Here's a full example, which also calls collect to make each parameter point to just the values:

```
all = [
    [parameter: 'foo', value: 'aaa'],
    [parameter: 'foo', value: 'bbb'],
    [parameter: 'bar', value: 'ccc'],
    [parameter: 'baz', value: 'ddd']
]
tmpMap = all.groupBy{it.parameter}
myMap = [:].putAll(tmpMap.collect{k, v -> [k, v.value] as MapEntry})

assert myMap == [foo: ['aaa', 'bbb'], bar: ['ccc'], baz:['ddd']]
```

Comment: +1 much better than my answer.  I code groovy as java...gets the job down, but not at cool....