# How to save categories and related subcategories in database using Grails

Tags: grails, dictionary, grails-orm

I have an enquiry page and this page has option to choose categories and subCategories while create new enquiry. For exaple:

```
Main Category
 Sub Category
 Sub Category
 Sub Category

Main Category
 Sub Category
 Sub Category
 Sub Category

Main Category
 Sub Category
 Sub Category
 Sub Category
```

User can select multiple categories and subcategories from enquiry page.

Followings are domain classed related to category and SubCategory:

**Category.groovy**

```
class Category {

    String name
    String description
    static constraints = {
    }
    static hasMany = [ subCategories: SubCategory ]

}
```

**SubCategory.groovy**

```
class SubCategory {

        String name

        static hasMany = [requirements: Enquiry]
        static belongsTo = [ category: Category]
        static constraints = {
            requirements nullable:true
        }
    }
```

**Note: Below domain is used to save selected categories and subcategories from enquiry page.**

```
class RegisteredCategories {

  Enquiry enquiry
  Category category

  static constraints = {

  }

  static hasMany = [ subCategories: SubCategory ]
}
```

**GSP template which display categories and subcategories on enquiry page:**

```
<g:each in="${marketlist}" status="j" var="category">
     <g:hiddenField  id="${j}"  name="catId.${category.id}" value="${category?.id}"  />
       <DIV class="market-name">
        <p>${category.name}</p>
       </DIV>
       <g:each in="${category.subCategories}" status="i" var="subCategory">
        <div>
            <g:checkBox class="cb1-element" id="check${i}"  name="subId.${subCategory.id}" value="on"/>
            <label for="check${i}" > ${subCategory.name}</label>
       </g:each>
    </g:each>
```

** Create action in EnquiryController.groovy  where I want to save categories and subcategories.**

```
 def create = { EnquiryCommand enquiryCommand ->

        def enquiry  = null
        try {
             enquiry = new Enquiry( params)
             //def sub = Category.get(params.catId)
              def sub = params.list('catId').get(0)
              def subCat= params.list('subId').get(0)

            //enquiry.properties = params

            /*
            def String[] tags = params.tagsList.split(",")
            for (def tag : tags) {
                Tag tagObject = new Tag();
                tagObject.tag = tag ;
                enquiry.addToTags( tagObject)
            }
                */

            int enquiryId = enquiryService.createEnquiry( enquiry ,enquiryCommand )
            if ( !enquiry.hasErrors()){
                flash.put("enquiry", "enquiry created")
                redirect( action: sentEnquiry )
            }else {
                render (view: "showCreateEnquiry" , model:["enquiryInstance" : enquiryCommand] )
            }
        }catch ( DataserviceException e ){
            render (view: "showCreateEnquiry" , model:["enquiryInstance" : enquiryCommand] )
        }
```

**Problem:**

How to get those multiple selected categories and subcategories in controller and save in db.
Someone suggested me that create a groovy Map in create action and get list of categories and subcategories from GSP template. Also advised me to use key of Map to store ids from categories and value to store list of subcategories ids related to that categories.

How could It can be done ?

Comment: hi @emilan, can I get help on this question?

Answer (score 2):

When you work with lists in `html` your `name` attribute must be the same, and you can identify the `id` of your class instance by the `value` attribute. Translating this to code, you have:

```
<g:each in="" var="sub">
  <g:checkBox name="subcategories" value="${sub.id}" />
</g:each>
```

And in your controller, you can transform the content of `params` in a `List` with:

```
def subcategories = params.list('subcategories')
```

Then all you need is to query your records by `id`.

```
subcategories.each { id ->
  SubCategory sub = SubCategory.get(id)
}
```

Comment: hi @sérgio-michels , I think for this solution, I may need to use Maps. for EX: all = [
    [parameter: 'foo', value: 'aaa'],
    [parameter: 'foo', value: 'bbb'],
    [parameter: 'bar', value: 'ccc'],
    [parameter: 'baz', value: 'ddd']
]

def myMap = [:].withDefault { [] }
all.each {
    myMap[it.parameter] << it.value
}
What you do think on this? Because A use can select multiple categories and from a category, multiple subcategories cab be selected. So Suppose, I select two subcategories from first category and one subcategory from another category, For this Map is best solution.

Comment: hi @sergio-michels , use can select multiple categories and subcategories. How to handle this one?

Comment: Use two lists, one for categories and another to subcategories.

Comment: hi @sergio-michels , I did  create following lists to get categories and subcategories.        def sub = params.list('catId').get(0)
     def subCat= params.list('subId').get(0). Is this fine? If yes, How could I use them with Map.?

Comment: hi @stefan-armbruster, can I get some help on this question. I want to do like you did in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122587/list-as-map-value-in-grails